# postgres left join using regular expression on a hstore?

Tags: regex, postgresql, left-join, hstore

i'm trying to do a left join on two tables with hstore columns:

```
  SELECT
    d.context->'hostname' AS hostname,
    r.data->'Site' AS site,
    r.data->'Region' AS rack,
    r.data->'Manufacturer' AS vendor,
    r.data->'ModelNumber' AS model_number,
  FROM dns AS d
    LEFT JOIN rack AS r ON
        d.context->'hostname' ~ r.context->'Name'
  ;
```

where both `dns` and `rack` have two hstore columns `context` and `data`; the condition on the left join is such that `rack.context->'Name'` may only contain a part of the fqdn'd `dns.context->'hostname'`.

however, when i try the above, i get

```
 ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ~ hstore
```

any ideas?

Comment: What postgres version? Could be an operator precedence thing? have you tried putting parentheses around the two hstore lookups to ensure they are both strings (if that is what you intend)

Answer (score 2):

You have a precedence issue. This:

```
d.context->'hostname' ~ r.context->'Name'
```

is being parsed like this:

```
d.context -> ('hostname' ~ r.context) -> 'Name'
```

so the `~` is trying to match the `'hostname'` TEXT value with the `r.context` HSTORE. Add some parentheses to force the issue:

```
(d.context->'hostname') ~ (r.context->'Name')
```

If we have a look at the [operator precedence table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE), you'll see this:

> - stuff that doesn't contain `~` or `->`
> - `(any other)`: all other native and user-defined operators
> - more stuff that doesn't contain `~` or `->`

So both `~` and `->` fall into the "other" category. I'd guess that `~` is added to the operator list before `->` since `~` is a native operator whereas `->` is added by the hstore extension.

---

Interestingly enough, the *more stuff that doesn't contain `~` or `->`* list does contain LIKE and this:

```
hstore1 -> k1 like hstore2 -> k2
```

works as expected so in here:

```
select 'a=>b'::hstore -> 'a' like 'a=>b'::hstore -> 'a';
select 'a=>b'::hstore -> 'a' ~    'a=>b'::hstore -> 'a';
```

the first query will be `'t'` whereas the second will produce your "operator does not exist" error. I only mention this because I would have expected the `LIKE`, `SIMILAR`, and `~` operators to have the same precedence since they're all variations on the same theme.

Comment: thanks for the response: so you're correct that using `LIKE` works as expected, however, i still cannot get the `~` operator to work. when i use `( d.context->'hostname' ) ~ ( r.context->'Name' )`, it comes back with `ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`

Comment: @yee379: What does `r.context->'Name'` look like in those cases? And a regex might not be the right solution at all, if you just want `r.context->'Name'` to be at the end of `d.context->'hostname'` then the [`position`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) string function might be a better idea than a regex.

Comment: `r.context->'Name'` is normally a non-fqdn'd hostname, so yes, using `LIKE (r.context->'Name' || '%') would work as it just compares to a fdqn'd hostname (not really sure position would be a great fit here). however, i was just confused as to why the `~` still wouldn't work - even when they are wrapped in parenthesis. cheers!